# Enforce field max length on LWC datatable editable column

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to add or enforce any sort of max length parameter on an editable field on an [LWC datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)? I was expecting to find a param I could add to the column config, but I can't find anything in the documentation. My current config is:

```
       { 
            label: Name, 
            fieldName: 'name', 
            editable: isEditable,
            type: 'text',
            hideDefaultActions: true
        }
```

The field I am editing has a max length of 80 characters, but currently you can add more than 80 characters through the datatable on edit, which results in a silent failure on the save. An err in the console but nothing the user can see.

Am I missing something or would I need to handle this programmatically on the save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the oncellchange or onsave events to fix data that needs to be fixed before/during the save cycle. This isn't really called out in the documentation directly, it's just a combination of oncellchange and the draftValues attribute to specify what the new value(s) should be.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming that for me. I was hoping for some way to enforce it in the UI. I don't like editing a users data without them seeing it.

Comment: With a bit of effort, you can enforce it in the UI.  See the section titled "Displaying Errors" in the `lightning-datatable` docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation